# Fetching and displaying images in a modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, fetch, jinja2

I'm implementing a feature where if a user clicks a thumbnail, a modal will pop up and the image will be fetched with javascript.

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='path/'+username+'/thumbnails/'+image)}}"
    uk-toggle="target: #show-images" onclick="showImage({{username}}, {{image}})">
{% endfor %}
```

Modal code for above uk-toggle

```
<div id="show-images" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-width-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-outside" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <img alt="Image Didn't Load" id="my_img">
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function showImage(username, imagename) {
fetch('path/'+username+'/'+imagename)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(function(response) {
        document.getElementById('my_img').src = URL.createObjectURL(response);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

I get an error and the image is not fetched and rendered in the modal.

Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
For another image, I get
Uncaught ReferenceError: caissalover is not defined

Thanks in advance. Image names can start with a number unlike javascript variables want.

Comment: I think the error here is that javascript searches for the variable username, in my case caissalover instead of getting string caissalover. Is there a way to convert given jinja2 input to string in javascript? Same goes for imagename, it searches for a variable 1foo.jpg instead of getting that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added single quotes outside jinja2 inputs. That solved it for me by converting variables to strings.

```
onclick="showImage('{{username}}', '{{image}}')"
```